# How to dynamically select a bean with multiple annotation

Tags: java, annotations, cdi, quarkus

Let's say I have several processors classes and each processor is able to handle one or two specific keys. I'm reading a file made of csv lines and each line has a key in one of the fields.
Then during the parsing of the file, I'm doing :

```
class Parser(){
@Inject
    @Any
    Instance<Processsor> processors;
(...)
while (null != (text = reader.readLine())) {//let's say we got a reader before this loop
      String key = getKeyFromLine(text);
      Processsor selectedProc = processors.select(new ProcessorQualifier(key)).get();
      selectedProc.processLine(text);
   }
}
```

ProcessorQualifier is like :

```
public class ProcessorQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<ProcAnnotation> implements ProcAnnotation {
    private ProcTypeEnum type;

    public ProcessorQualifier(ProcTypeEnum type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public ProcTypeEnum procTypes() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly as soon as I have processors with only one Annotation :

```
@ProcAnnotation(type=key1)
class Key1Processor implements Processor{
    void processLine(String text){
        ...
    }
```

But if I want my Key1Processor to be selected for key1 **OR** key2 then I don't know how to do.
If I put 2 annotations on my class processor : it doesn't compile

```
Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type @ProcAnnotation. Only annotation types marked @Repeatable can be used multiple times at one target.
```

then I created a Repeatable annotation :

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@javax.enterprise.inject.Stereotype 
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE })
@Dependent
public @interface ProcAnnotations {
    ProcAnnotation[] value();
}
```

But I'm stuck because I don't know how to select (`processors.select(???)`) the processor that have one of its key matching the key parsed in text.
But as far as I can understand `processors.select(new ProcessorQualifier(key))` iterates over all instances of `Processors` and select the one which matches its annotation with `ProcessorQualifier` then the problem is which `ProcessorQualifier` to have/write ? More generally, how to dynamically select a bean by one of its qualifier ?

Comment: Maybe the annotation type property could be an array?  `@ProcAnnotation(types = { key1, key2 })`

Comment: Yes, it could but it doesn't change anything. I create a `ProcQualifier` that is used in `select` and then CDI iterates over all  instances and then compares arrays ; I'd like it to match if one of the item of the array matches the key.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment

> I'd like it to match if one of the item of the array matches the key.

I suggest the following.

Let's assume that is a service interface

```java
public interface Desired {
    String getFoo();
}
```

and some implementation

```java
@Selector("one")
@Dependent
@Unremovable
public class InstanceOne implements Desired{
    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "one";
    }
}
```

```java
@Selector("two")
@Dependent
@Unremovable
public class InstanceTwo implements Desired {
    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "two";
    }
}
```

```java
@Selector("one")
@Selector("two")
@Dependent
@Unremovable
public class InstanceOneTwo  implements Desired {
    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "one and two";
    }
}
```

```java
@Selector("three")
@Dependent
@Unremovable
public class InstanceThree implements Desired {
    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "three";
    }
}
```

```java
@Selector("four")
@Selector("five")
@Selector("six")
@Dependent
@Unremovable
public class InstanceFourToSix implements Desired {
    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "four or five, maybe six";
    }
}
```

If you want to put an annotation multiple times it should be `@Repeatable`

```java
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
@Repeatable(Selector.List.class) 
public @interface Selector {
    String value();

    @Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface List {
        Selector[] value();
    }
}
```

and the annotationLiteral is:

```java
class SelectorLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Selector> implements Selector {
    private final String value;

    public SelectorLiteral(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

From now there are multiple aproach to select one or more instances.

```java
@Any
@Inject
Instance<Desired> instances;
```

```java
// will select and initiate InstanceFourToSix
instances.select(new SelectorLiteral("five")).get();

// will select and initiate InstanceFourToSix
instances.select(new SelectorLiteral("six")).get();

// will select and initiate InstanceOneTwo
instances.select(new SelectorLiteral("two"),new SelectorLiteral("one")).get();

// will throw javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException
// because both InstanceOne and InstanceOneTwo is qualified with 'two' literal
instances.select(new SelectorLiteral("two")).get();

// will select both InstanceOne and InstanceOneTwo and call getFoo() method on all selected instances, and so on 
instances.select(new SelectorLiteral("two")).stream()
    .map(Desired::getFoo) // all stream operation is also available e.g. filter()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```